# FM Transmitter Power and approx Transmission Distance Calculation

Tags: rf, transmitter, frequency-modulation

I am a beginner of electronics and mostly fascinated by hobby circuits right now. I do not have any Electronics Degree. Internet and hobby Electronics books are the only places where I learned lill-bit of Electronics. One of the most popular circuits being shared by Experts on internet and in those books is an FM Transmitter.

I've made a so-called 'powerful FM transmitter' and measured the peak current across the Amplifying transistor's collector-emmitter. It reads approx 300mA. The overall circuit consumes approx 400mA. I am operating the circuit at 16V.

Sorry for the 3 questions, all at once. But I guess they are related.

1. Is this one really a 4.8 Watt FM Transmitter? If not, how do you
   calculate the Wattage of FM Transmission of a typical FM Transmitter?
2. How the wattage of the transmitter is related to dB
   rating of a transmitter?
3. Is there a formula/rule to calculate how much distance an FM signal can propagate in open and obstructed (populated) areas?

Comment: With less than 25W "you" can go billions of km: https://science.howstuffworks.com/question431.htm

Comment: Rather obviously, even though performing well below your hopes, the device described is illegal.  Were it a legal device, it would have been designed, tested, and certified by someone well knowing the answers to these questions.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am taking care of the legal aspect! Thanks for reminding and taking your time to write it down once again in FM Transmitter related thread! I was expecting an "it's not legal" comment on my question, most of the questions related to FM transmitters  has a 'non answer' comment like yours!! Lol! :)

Comment: Rather obviously you **are not** taking care of the legal aspect, as if you were, this question would have been answered *by that process* since it is a fundamental part of gaining legal authorization to do something like this.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes, I'm in the process, and see below, some people (part of the process) have actually responded with  answers. Thanks again for being the guardian of RF spectrum!!

Comment: As paths that let the uninformed operate home built transmitters in this power class simply don't exist, your claim is false. The only real remaining question is if you know that and are lying to us in order to gain assistance in creating a "pirate" radio station; or if you are so naive as to actually still not understand the simple fact that **you will not be able to gain authorization to do this**.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Now that's a piece of personal attack and should be flagged as 'inappropriate'! You've shown your class! No more thanksgiving!

Comment: That there is no process by which a home built ~5 watt broadcast transmitter can be licensed for use in your alleged location of Irvine California without review by a certified party (who would look at this issue *and many others*) is a statement of fact.

Comment: Why does this question seem unspecific, broad or unrelated. The questions are absolutely specific and I've got answers too. Is it put on hold because I reported a predictable and template complete of a SE member who has higher Reputation? I never knew this place to be so autocracy! Please explain how I can make this question more 'specific'.

Comment: @ laptop2d, @ PeterJ do you think there is a valid reason to classify the question as any of - 'broad', 'unspecific', 'unrelated'? Or you've just moved by the fact that a reputed SE members predictable comments were lolled at?

Comment: I am not sure why this question is reported as 'too broad' days after 2 most authentic SE Electronics experts have found a reason to answer the question and I've accepted an answer. I didn't know this is the place to show such autocracy!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've made a 'powerful FM transmitter' and measured the peak current
>   across the Amplifying transistor's collector-emmitter. It reads approx
>   300mA.

You are measuring current incorrectly. Putting a meter across C and E will just take a large amount of current that is unrelated to the current flowing through C and E in normal operation.

Additionally I suspect that you are measuring DC current and not the carrier wave current - most meters will **not** happily measure RMS current in the VHF/FM band.

> how do you calculate the Wattage of FM Transmission of a typical FM
>   Transmitter?

Measuring the voltage at the antenna is the only direct way. If you antenna is a quarter wave monopole it will have a radiation resistance of about 37 ohms and so if you have 2 V RMS (VHF/FM) then the output power will be 4/37 = 108 mW.

If you are using a badly tuned antenna the power might be just a fraction of the "perfect" scenario. For instance, if your antenna is short of the desired length then its radiation resistance will rapidly fall to a few ohms and more your antenna signal level will fall due to this lower impedance. So if the antenna only presented 4 ohms radiation resistance (because it is too short in length) then it is likely that the 2 V RMS will fall to about one-tenth and then power out is \$0.4^2/4\$ = 40 mW.

> How the wattage of the transmitter is related to dB rating of a
>   transmitter?

1 watt is 1000 mW and, in dBm terms this is 10 log (1000) dBm = 30 dBm.

> Typically, from your experience please tell me how much distance
>   should I expect this transmitter to cover in a densely populated
>   residential area? Is there a formula/rule to calculate this?

It depends so much on many things and many people have laboured over this for decades. A simple free-space formula is called the Friis path loss model: -

Path loss (dB) = 32.45 + 20\$log_{10}\$(f) + 20\$log_{10}\$(d)

Where f is in MHz and d is in kilometres. This equation tells you how many dB of power loss you can expect at a given distance with a given carrier frequency: -

[image]

Here is a model that considers obstacles: -

[image]

There is also the Okumura model and the Hata urban propagation model (based on Okumura's model). See [my answer here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/83512/long-range-15-km-low-baud-rate-wireless-communication-in-a-mountain-environme) for other details.

Comment: just overwhelmed by this detailed answer. I got most of it. Thanks specially for the Non Line of Sight propagation calculation.

Comment: Hi @Andy aka do you think this question was too broad?

Comment: @amanda it’s borderline and i nearly voted to close it myself but decided I could make a decent answer to a clearly written question. It’s also borderline soliciting opinions as you asked for experiences. It’s almost too broad in that your personal details didn’t tell much about your skills hence an answer’s starting point was cloudy. But given I visited Irvine and did some shopping there in 2015 I though.... give the lady a break. Laguna is where I stayed, nice,

Comment: Thanks for your answers Sir! I got my doubts clarified and learned from it. My last question was actually related to the formula which you provided, may be by words the first part of the last question sounds like soliciting opinion. I'd love to correct it right away!
Laguna is great! By the way, until experts like you give break to newbies like me, it's pretty difficult to learn a topic like Electronics at my age!

Answer (score 3):

1. No

That is supply current,  efficiency will be < 60% and is measured by ratio with Pout.

Try different loads (50~300) such as 50 Ohm load, non-inductive, rated 5W with very short leads and measure Vpp then convert to Pd (rms) by \$\frac{V^2pp}{  8R_L}\$

2. 10 log Pd(rms) = [dB] or + 30dB for dBm (0dBm=1mW)
3. There are many variables such as antenna impedance matching losses , directional gain ( e.g. Yagi)  for Tx, Rx and Rx noise level.  Look for a **[Friis Loss](http://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Friis-Calculator.phtml)** calculator and this applies to line of sight.

Comment: Voyager's Radios use extemely low baud rates with high FM deviation ratios in a quiet band at 8GHz so it can communicate with very high gain antenna, billions of miles away with a few minutes of latency.

Comment: Hi @Tony do you think this question was too broad or unspecific?